# Palabras "reservadas" de PHP que no puedo usar

Tags: php

Estoy armándome un script en PHP que lo que hace es generar el texto que va dentro de un archivo .php, desde allí recorro tabla y demás cosas, pero cuando quiero usar la palabra, por ejemplo, `$_POST[]`, me genera un error, ¿cómo tengo que poner `$_POST[]` para que me lo escriba y muestre en pantalla? ¿de qué forma puedo "enmascarar" este tipo de palabra como para que en la pantalla me muestre la palabra correcta?

Paso un ejemplo:

```
$script_php .= "# Generamos la sección de grabación después del POST :".$enter;


$script_php .= "if(isset($_POST['btn_grabar']))".$enter;                     


$script_php .= "{".$enter;                                                     


$script_php .= "$".$primary_key." = $SESSION['".$primary_key."']".$enter;
```

Lo que quiero es visualizar algo así como :

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_grabar'])) 

    $id_hipodromo = $_SESSION['id_'];

    $id_animal=$_POST['id_animal'];
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
```

Comment: Estás teniendo problemas con la interpretación de variables cuando se usan dobles comillas. Redactando respuesta.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿eso quieres mostrarlo en una página web y que mantenga el formato?

Answer (score 4):

Cuando usas cadenas de caracteres delimitadas por [comillas dobles (`"`)](http://php.net/types.string#language.types.string.syntax.double) estás permitiendo la interpretación de variables en su interior, por eso trata de convertir `$_POST` por su valor.

De modo que el problema no es el uso de "palabras reservadas" en una cadena de caracteres, si no el uso de variables dentro de ellas cuando se usan comillas dobles o [heredoc](http://php.net/types.string#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Para evitar que las variables se interpreten dentro de cadenas de caracteres tienes dos opciones:

## [Comillas sencillas (`'`)](http://php.net/types.string#language.types.string.syntax.single)

```
$script_php = 'if(isset($_POST[\'btn_grabar\'])) {
    $id_hipodromo = $_SESSION[\'id_\'];
    $id_animal = $_POST[\'id_animal\'];
    $nombre = $_POST[\'nombre\'];
}';
```

En este caso debes acordarte de escapar las comillas sencillas con una contrabarra delante (`\` ).

## [Nowdoc](http://php.net/types.string#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

```
$script_php = <<<'FINAL'
if(isset($_POST['btn_grabar'])) {
    $id_hipodromo = $_SESSION['id_'];
    $id_animal = $_POST['id_animal'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
}
FINAL;
```

En este caso no debes preocuparte por escapar ningún carácter. Únicamente de no introducir la cadena de final a tu código.

Fíjate que heredoc no es válido porque, al igual que las dobles comillas, también interpreta valores de variables.

## Salida al navegador

Si quieres mostrar ese código en el navegador deberás usar la etiqueta HTML `<pre>` o `<code>` y, además, convertir a entidades los caracteres especiales con [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
<pre><?= htmlspecialchars($script_php) ?></pre>
```

O bien:

```
<code style="white-space: pre;"><?= htmlspecialchars($script_php) ?></code>
```

Por cierto, tienes a tu disposición la constante [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/reserved.constants#constant.php-eol) que representa un final de línea en tu plataforma. Deberías pensar usarla en vez de tu variable `$enter`.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacerlo al menos de tres maneras.

### Forma 1: Desde código PHP

Escribes todo el fragmento de código en una cadena almacenándolo en una variable. Pero necesitas hacer un cambio en la forma de usar las comillas: al inicio y al final de la cadena debes usar comillas simples `'` y en las variables de dentro comillas dobles `"`, de lo contrario, las variables se interpretarán como tales y no es lo que interesa aquí.

Luego imprimes dicha cadena usando [`highlight_string`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.highlight-string.php). Es una función de PHP que hace lo siguiente según el Manual:

> Imprime o devuelve marcas html para una versión con la sintaxis
>   remarcada del código de PHP dado usando los colores definidos en el
>   remarcador de sintaxis interno de PHP.

De ese modo te mostrará el código identado y (según dice el Manual, con colores, según la configuración de colores de PHP).

Este sería el código:

```
$strCode='
if(isset($_POST["btn_grabar"]))    
    $id_hipodromo = $_SESSION["id_"];
    $id_animal=$_POST["id_animal"];
    $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];';
echo highlight_string($strCode);
```

#### Resultado en pantalla:

```
if(isset($_POST["btn_grabar"]))
    $id_hipodromo = $_SESSION["id_"];
    $id_animal=$_POST["id_animal"];
    $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
```

---

### Forma 2: Mezcla de PHP y HTML

Abres un bloque HTML en tu PHP y muestras el código. En este caso, como estás en HTML, puedes dejar lo de las comillas simples como lo tenías originalmente, ya que estás en HTML y las variables no se interpretarán como variables de PHP.

```
<?php

//Código PHP

?>
<html>
<body>    
<code>
if(isset($_POST['btn_grabar'])) <br />
    $id_hipodromo = $_SESSION['id_']; <br />
    $id_animal=$_POST['id_animal']; <br />
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];   <br />
</code> 
</body>
</html>
```

#### Resultado en pantalla:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_grabar'])) 
$id_hipodromo = $_SESSION['id_']; 
$id_animal=$_POST['id_animal']; 
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
```

Aquí el problema es que el código no se muestra identado.

---

### Forma 3: con una librería externa

Puedes usar una librería para mostrar código identado y con colores, por ejemplo [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). Esta es la forma que suelen usar los sitios que trabajan mostrando ejemplos de código.

Sólo tendrías que agregar la librería (JS), como cualquier otra:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

Y luego abrir una etiqueta así:

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-php">
```

Aquí se indica que quiere la sintaxis de PHP mediante `lang-php`, para el color de código.

Luego escribes dentro el código debidamente identado y al final cierras la etiqueta `</pre>`.

Veamos una prueba. Aquí estamos en HTML, se puede hacer en PHP, agregando a la cadena lo necesario. Pulsa en <kbd>**`Ejecutar`**</kbd>, para ver el resultado.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>


<pre class="prettyprint lang-php">
if(isset($_POST['btn_grabar'])) 
    $id_hipodromo = $_SESSION['id_']; 
    $id_animal=$_POST['id_animal']; 
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
</pre>
```

Comment: Ya tenías mi +1, ¿cómo puedo darte otro +1 adicional por lo del `highlight_string`? Hacía siglos que no hacía uso de ella xD Habría que añadir [`highlight-file`](http://php.net/highlight-file) si lo que quiere es enviar el contenido de un archivo PHP al navegador con color en el formato de código.