# Desarrollo web y apps: Mostrar código html colorido

Tags: html, web, aplicación-web, app

Para una app de carácter didáctico que estoy desarrollando necesito que el código html se me vea colorido en función de la sintaxis.Yo sé como introducir código html en una página web, a través de la etiqueta `<code>` pero no sé como hacer para que me coloree la sintáxis. Ya de paso me vendría bien que lo hiciera para lenguajes de programación como python, c o javascript. ¿Hay alguna etiqueta en html qué me permita hacer eso?

Les comparto mi código a través de codepen. Lo que necesito es que la parte que está subrayada en azul, con un icono que índica que se trata de código, sea coloreada.

See the Pen [Theory Block](https://codepen.io/Baldan/pen/yEpxxq/) by Guillermo ([@Baldan](https://codepen.io/Baldan)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: ¿Te refieres a colorear las etiquetas que aparecen dentro de code de diferentes colores?

Comment: No tiene pinta que el tag code se use para eso, parece que se usa como se usa el tag strong, simplemente cambia el formato, pero no hay mas inteligencia en ello.

Comment: Te reenlazo a otra pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756164/how-to-print-code-on-html

Comment: Mira [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/137150/29967). Quizá para el caso que expones convendría usar una librería externa, como se explica al final, en el apartado que dice **Forma 3**.

Comment: @asantanao: Si, a eso me refiero

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En este caso puedes usar una librería externa, por ejemplo, **`code-prettify` de Google**.

Su uso es muy sencillo, bastan dos sencillos pasos:

- Primer paso: incluyes la librería mediante `<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>`
- Segundo paso: Escribes el código dentro de un bloque:

  ```
  <pre class="prettyprint lang-aquí_el_lenguaje">  

        //...código 

  </pre>
  ```

Y listo.

Aunque también la librería cuenta con otras funcionalidades interesantes, como una [Galería de Temas](https://rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/styles/index.html) y otras cosas que podrás encontrar revisando el [proyecto en Github](https://github.com/google/code-prettify).

Aquí te dejo algunos ejemplos:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>

<h2>Javascript</h2>
<pre class="prettyprint lang-javascript">

const btn = document.getElementById('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Hello World!');
});


</pre>

<h2>Java</h2>

<pre class="prettyprint lang-java">
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}

</pre>

<h2>C</h2>

<pre class="prettyprint lang-c">
int main()
{
   // printf() displays the string inside quotation
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 5):

Si te refieres a colorear el código que pones de ejemplo como se vería en algunos IDE o editores de texto lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar una librería como te ha comentado Cedano.

Pero si el código que quieres colorear es poco y quieres personalizarlo podrías hacerlo usando span con las clases personalizadas que necesites.

```css
code {background: black; color: white;padding: 10px;margin: 5px;}
.etiqueta {color:purple;}
.atributo {color: green;}
.valor {color:yellow;}
```

```html
<p>Ejemplo de codigo HTML con colores:</p>
<code>
  &nbsp&nbsp&lt
  <span class="etiqueta">img</span> 
  <span class="atributo">draggable</span>=
  <span class="valor">"true"</span> 
  <span class="atributo">alt</span>=
  <span class="valor">"Alt de la imagen"</span>
  &gt
</code>
<p>Aquí otro ejemplo de código HTML coloreado:</p>
<code>
  &nbsp&nbsp&lt
  <span class="etiqueta">div</span> 
  <span class="atributo">class</span>=
  <span class="valor">"div_prueba"</span> 
  <span class="atributo">id</span>=
  <span class="valor">"id_prueba"</span>
  &gt
</code>
```

Es una opción pero al menos que sea algo muy especial es mejor que uses una librería.

Answer (score 0):

Otra solucion, Bootstrap tiene este elemento. y es unas de las librerias mas comunes que usamos

```html
<link  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"rel='stylesheet'>


Si quieres ver el codigo en bootstrap debes usar la etiqueta &ltpre&gt: 

<pre>
&ltlink  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"rel='stylesheet'>
</pre>
```